# OnClick does not work to Preventt in ActionLink -ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a ActionLink Like this :

```
    @Html.ActionLink("Add New", MVC.Admin.Purchase.Create(), new { @class = "btn btn-success", onclick = "return checkDefaultStore();" })
```

html result above code is :

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-success" href="/Admin/Purchase/Create" onclick="return checkDefaultStore();">Add New</a>
```

I want before go to new Page check a something and if that not exists prevent to go to new page .

For this I create this  JQuery function :

```
function checkDefaultStore(e) {
var url = $('#ajax-info').data('checkdefaultstore');
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: {},
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.result)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    },
    error: function (response) {

    }
});
}
```

Action method which defined return `false` or `true`.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public virtual JsonResult HasDefault()
    {
        bool result = _storeService.HasDefault();
        if (result)
            return Json(new { result = true },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        else
            return Json(new { result = false, message = "default store does not exists" },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

when click on link , it calls function and go to new Page.

Comment: Your using an overload of `ActionLink()` that is ading both the class name and the javascript function as route parameters. You never even hit your function.

Comment: If even if did, it would not prevent the redirect (its already occurred by the time you ajax function returns a value. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @StephenMuecke when click on link , its call function and call ActionMethod , but don't run `success function` or `error function` in ajax

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/iZx7pb

Comment: in above `dotnetfiddle` , just replace `T4MVC` with `static param`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111273/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-uthman-rahimi).

Comment: You solution does not work because your `if` block of code will be executed before your ajax call has returned a result.

Comment: oh , yes your right , why `if` block run befor ajax call , is there a way to do this ?

Comment: I already mentioned 3 ways in the chat comments :)

Comment: ok , thanks a lot :)

Comment: I have deleted your 'solution' :) I'll add an answer a little later explaining the issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your link will always redirect because ajax calls are async and by the time your controller returns the result, the browser has already redirected to the other page.

You options are (in order of preference)

1. Check the value of `_storeService.HasDefault()` in the GET method
   that generates your view, and if `false`, then do not generate the
   link in the first place (no script required).
2. Remove the `onclick` from the link and just let it redirect to your
   `Create()` method. In that method check the value of
   `_storeService.HasDefault()` and if false, return the view with the
   error message (no script required)
3. Make the redirect in the ajax success callback using
   `location.href`. You code would be

```js
    <a href="#" id="create">Add New</a>

    $('#create').click(function() {
        var url = $('#ajax-info').data('checkdefaultstore');
        $.post(url, function(data) {
            if (data.result)
                location.href = '@Url.Action("Create", "Purchase", new { area = "Admin" }';
            else
                alert(data.message);
            }
        });
    });
```